# input[type="file"]で、(webkitDirectoryを使用せず)ディレクトリを丸ごと選択する方法はありますか？

Tags: javascript, html5

**やりたいこと**
multiple で複数ファイル選択ではなく、指定ディレクトリ内の全ファイル選択をしたい

**Q**
下記リンク先に「HTMLInputElement.directory」と記載されているのですが何のことですか？

> [HTMLInputElement.directoryとは異なり、このプロパティの値をtrueにしてもHTMLInputElement.filesプロパティはnullにはなりません。](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitDirectory)

[英語ページ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/webkitDirectory)も見てみたのですが良く分かりませんでした。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問の記述そのものは、マウスカーソルを重ねると、「 **この項目についての文書はまだ書かれていません。書いてみませんか？** 」と出てくるので、そのとおり、まだ書かれていないのでしょう。

こちらのページに記載されている内容が当てはまりそうですが、つい最近と思われる「Draft Community Group Report, 26 June 2019」となっていても、該当プロパティの記述はありません。
[File and Directory Entries API](https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/)

これから標準化されていく、まだまだ作業途中のものだと思われます。

[Can I use](https://caniuse.com/#search=directory) とかにも出てこないので、とりあえず、その記述は無視しておいて良いのではないでしょうか？

なおちなみに、こちら [HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) に`allowdirs`というプロパティが Firefox にだけ隠しで存在すると書かれています。

> Boolean: Part of the non-standard Directory Upload API; **indicates** whether or not to allow directories and files both to be selected in the file list. Implemented only in Firefox and is hidden behind a preference.
>
> 非標準のディレクトリアップロードAPIの一部。 ファイルリストでディレクトリとファイルの両方を選択できるようにするかどうかを示します。 Firefoxでのみ実装されており、設定の背後に隠れています。

Comment: 蛇足ですが、Directory Upload の `allowdirs` 属性に関する記述の [blame](https://github.com/WICG/directory-upload/blame/05dced3f6f7f3158d4a422b8921952be428e7b37/proposal.html#L214) を見たところによれば、3 年ほど前に [`directory` 属性の名前が `allowdirs` 属性に変更された](https://github.com/WICG/directory-upload/commit/dcf70e093ddd39523cd7f0455ac66b02dbd02502)ようです。

Comment: なるほど、存在しないプロパティなのですね。コメントを読んで、(Firefoxでのみ実装されている)directory 属性の名前が allowdirs 属性に変更された際の、単なる変更し忘れではないかと思いました

Answer (score 1):

現在、`webkitDirectory` を使う以外の方法はありません。
Chrome、Edge, Firefox, Safari で使えますし、`webkit`プレフィックスがついたまま[標準化の最中](https://wicg.github.io/entries-api/#html-forms)なので利用を避ける必要はないと思います。

MDNの`HTMLInputElement.directory`に関する記述は意味不明ですね。英語ページには記述がありませんし、無視すべきかと思います。

Comment: ＞標準化の最中なので利用を避ける必要はないと思います。リンク提示ありがとうございます。標準化が途中でダメになったのかと勝手に誤解していました。webkitDirectoryを使用したいと思います